# Performance of count for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I wonder the count operation in mongodb for large collection.

When I do `db.collection.count()` without any criteria in a collection with ten million rows, it just take no more than 100ms.

Why so fast, is it just read from the stat value of `db.collection.stats().count`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `count()` without a query predicate is a fast/estimated count read from the collection statistics, so should return in constant time regardless of the total number of documents. This is the same value returned by `db.collection.stats().count` and the [`$collStats` aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/) (MongoDB 3.6+). Note: with the WiredTiger storage engine, collection statistics are persisted periodically and [may not be accurate after unclean shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown).

A `count()` with query criteria will provide a more accurate result, but will need to iterate a suitable index (or perform a collection scan if there are no candidate indexes).

You can confirm the query planning outcome by reviewing the `explain()` output for a count.

The winning plan for a fast count only has a `COUNT` stage:

```
> db.zipcodes.explain().count().queryPlanner.winningPlan
{ "stage" : "COUNT" }
```

The winning plan for a count using an index will have a `COUNT_SCAN` input stage:

```
> db.zipcodes.explain().count({city:'Sydney'}).queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
    "stage" : "COUNT",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "city" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "city_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "city" : [ ]
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "startKey" : {
                "city" : "Sydney"
            },
            "startKeyInclusive" : true,
            "endKey" : {
                "city" : "Sydney"
            },
            "endKeyInclusive" : true
        }
    }
}
```

The winning plan for a count requiring a collection scan will have a `COLLSCAN` input stage:

```
> db.zipcodes.explain().count({cityx:'Sydney'}).queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
    "stage" : "COUNT",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "cityx" : {
                "$eq" : "Sydney"
            }
        },
        "direction" : "forward"
    }
}
```

Comment: Model.count() is deprecated. Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168420/7399485

Answer (score 1):

The operation does not perform the query but instead counts the results that would be returned by the query. You can check this by looking into query plan for it using EXPLAIN

db.collection.explain("executionStats").count()

Comment: So it just read from the counter of "some stat"? where is the stats store, any document mention it?

Comment: So if I wanted a users entire article count and also a limited set of 10 using various params, I would be better off running two seperate queries on the mongodb in a promise. I would not get all articles, count them for the count and then filter the ones i want using the params ?