# mongoose count query taking too much time, Need to reduce time

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get a total number of count of some documents. I am using mongoose count query. When I am trying to find documents like 85k, at that time, It's taking 12 seconds. I need to reduce the time to 2 or 3 seconds.
It just an example, There could be several hundreds of thousands of data which has to be counted. I think it will take too much time.

Here is the query which I am using to count documents

```
Donor.count(find_cond, function (er, doc) {
    console.log(doc, "doc")
});
```

when it will count 10k to 20k, It's fine. when It goes to more than that it will too much time-consuming, It should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this..

```
Donor.createIndex({field1:1, field2:1, field3:1});
Donor.find({"field1" : "val1", "field2" : "val2"}).sort({field3: -1}).limit(100000).lean().count().exec();
```

1. Index is used for fast retrieval of data from database.
2. Performance can be improved by optimal equality -> sort -> range index.
3. Also, objects returned when using lean() are plain Javascript objects. Usually, Mongoose objects are returned in normal query.
   This [article](https://codeandcodes.com/2014/07/31/mongodb-performance-enhancements-and-tweaks/) provides useful guidelines for mongodb performance improvement.

Comment: I have tried this `Donor.aggregate([{ "$match": find_cond },{"$group": {"_id": null,"count": { "$sum": 1 }}}]`. Still I couldn't get any diffrence ? Can you correct me

Comment: I had updated my answer. Please let me know if this solution increases the performance.

Comment: Nope, It still taking 12 second to count 85k documents :( , https://codeshare.io/21XnVj here is the code you can look at it and correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @ShivamRaj take a look at my answer. My query was also taking over 12s and now takes about 2.5s

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little late but will write for future reference. After looking for a while, the best way I found to count documents is to use `estimatedDocumentCount()`, which uses collection metadata.

Another way for a very large collection (over 200k documents) is through the `Model.collection.stats()` method which will return an object with a key "count" like in this example:

```
const stats = await User.collection.stats();
const userCount = stats.count
```

It's still not great but the performance is much much better than `countDocuments()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Index for the field you try to get the count of.

Comment: I have tried to use Indexes but could not do it. how can I define indexes, here is the codebase https://codeshare.io/21XnVj . Can you please have a look and correct me.

Comment: if you are using mongoose you can use its property called Index. but it gives a deprecation warning from mongoDb. which is from originally mongodb. You can test it using
new Schema({
      name: {type: String, index: true}
});