# Best way to count documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

we have a collection with big amount of documents, lets say around 100k. We now want to count the number of documents which has the key `x` set.

If I try it with `Collection.countDocuments({ x: { $exists: true }})` I get the result, but it creates instantly a warning in the console: **Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000**.

So, is there a better way to count the documents? There is a `Index` on the field, is it possible to get the length of the index?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of documents in a mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720050/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: `Collection.find({}).count()` seems faster, but it’s deprecated so it will probably be removed any time…

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168420/7399485

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theres no real way of viewing the index trees in Mongo, what other people have linked you just returns the size of the tree, I'm not sure how useful that information is in this context.

Now to your question is this the best way to count?.
The answer is Yes ... -ish.

[countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mechanics) is a wrapper function, it just simulates the following pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: <query> },
   { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } } )
])
```

This pipeline is the most efficient way to go, but the difference between running this aggregation and using the wrapper function is about 100-200 milliseconds, depending on your machine spec.

Meaning if you're looking for "way" better performance you're not going to find it.

With that said this warning is stupid, it just means you have more than 1000 documents with that field. The true purpose of it is to alert you in the case you're trying to query 1-20 documents without a proper index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexSizes` field returned by the `stats()` method.
The `stats()` method "Returns statistics about the collection".

See example here :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#basic-stats-lookup

```
{
    ...,
    "indexSizes" : {
      "_id_" : 237568,
      "cuisine_1" : 143360,
      "borough_1_cuisine_1" : 151552,
      "borough_1_address.zipcode_1" : 151552
    },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is that the number of documents in the index or the storage size of the index? And unless it is a sparse index, the index would also contain documents that miss the field, no?

Comment: This is only the size of the index and not the length or count

Answer (score 1):

indexSize key return size as in space used in storing not count

Check With Explain if index getting used or not . (Update in question Also)

can use hint option to check the performance after specifying index

Or precalculate count by $inc operator might good option  if possible in you use case

try cursor.count if its faster  countDocument should been faster but no harm in checking
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/